# RegExp to validate the string "900 - 09 999"

Tags: javascript, regex

What would be the correct Javascript RegExp to validate the following string "900 - 09 999"
The string should only allow digits from 0 to 9, an hyphen and a space.

Thanks in advance

Comment: This is a basic regex skill that you can acquire by reading a few basic examples and fire up a regex editor. http://www.regular-expressions.info/ and http://rubular.com/

Comment: _Please_ be more precise when telling us what it's supposed to validate - Does the string include the quotes? Does the hyphen need to be there? What if the user drops or adds a space? What if they copy and paste a tab instead of a space somewhere? Is whitespace allowed at the beginning or the end? do you want it reformatted to look like that if it is pretty close, but not exact?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Always be precise when you explain what you want your regex to validate. Are the spaces and hyphens optional or not? This stuff matters. Anyway, this validates the strict format:

```
"\d{3} \- \d{2} \d{3}"
```

And this a less strict one:

```
"\d{3} ?\-? ?\d{2} ?\d{3}"
```

Comment: Thx. Klaus!! Yeah, the spaces & hyphens are optional.

Answer (score 0):

If you use this:

```
inputField.value = inputField.value.replace(/\s*(\d\d\d)\s*-?\s*(\d\d)\s*(\d\d\d)\s*/, "$1 - $2 $3")
```

...it should both loosely validate AND reformat the value if it does not match perfectly.

broken down, the expression does the following:

```
\s*          # match any amount of whitespace
(\d\d\d)     # capture three digits
\s*          # match any amount of whitespace
-?           # match an optional hyphen
\s*          # match any amount of whitespace
(\d\d)       # capture two digits
\s*          # match any amount of whitespace
(\d\d\d)     # capture three digits
\s*          # match any amount of whitespace
```

- `match` means to find a set of characters that matches the expression
- `capture` means to find a match, but store the match for later use
- `whitespace` can be spaces, tabs or carriage return characters
- `any amount` can mean zero or more